# Module build failed: Error: Debug Failure. False expression

Tags: angular, typescript, compilation

I have a library in typescript that compiles a class to javascript to:

```
ClassName = ClassName_1 = class ClassName{
...
}

ClassName = ClassName_1 = decorate([
...])
```

This gives an error when I compile with a angular frontend that depends on this library:

```
./node_modules/.bin/ng build --configuration=development --base-href /client/ --deploy-url /client/
```

The following error is given:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/library/ClassName.js
Module build failed: Error: Debug Failure. False expression.
```

I compile everything with typescript `2.9.2` as it is an Angular 6 project. I tried `7.0.0-rc` with `3.0.3 but I still have this error, but I might have a false negative here.

If I manually change the .js file it works:

```
ClassName = class ClassName{
...
}
ClassName_1 = ClassName

ClassName = ClassName_1 = decorate([
...])
ClassName_1 = ClassName
```

The code that has this error is:

```
/**
 * Endpoint gives the baseDomain of MultiChat and gives the appropriate protocol.
 * This is useful so you can pass through the same object to resources and streams types.
 *
 * A custom object is introduced to allow to pass the same object to use for WebSockets and https calls.
 * Paths are also added to easily construct full routes.
 *
 * The design is to return full new objects so that you do not mix references.
 */
@injectable()
export class Endpoint {

    public secure: boolean;
    public baseDomain: string;
    public paths: string[];
    public port: number;
    public queries: Map<string, string>;

    /**
     * init initializes the Endpoint with the correct baseDomain.
     * @param secure is true if the _endpoint is reachable by HTTPS and WSS
     * @param baseDomain the basedomain of the _endpoint, eg. independer.nl.
     * @param paths additional paths to the _endpoint without slashes, eg. ["api"]
     * @param port the port the _endpoint is hosted on
     */
    constructor(secure: boolean, baseDomain: string, paths: string[] = [], port?: number) {
        this.baseDomain = baseDomain;
        this.paths = paths;
        this.port = port;
        this.secure = secure;
        this.queries = new Map<string, string>();
    }

    /**
     * addPath returns a new Endpoint object with the paths added and returns a clone of the Endpoint.
     * @param paths
     */
    public addPath(paths: string[]): Endpoint {
        const result = this.cloneEndpoint();

        result.paths = this.paths.concat(paths);

        return result;

    }

    /**
     * addQuery adds a new query parameter and returns a clone of the Endpoint.
     * @param key The key of the parameter.
     * @param value The value of the parameter.
     */
    public addQuery(key: string, value: string): Endpoint {
        const result = this.cloneEndpoint();

        result.queries.set(key, value);

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * getHTTP returns the HTTP baseDomain string.
     * If the baseDomain is secure it returns HTTPS.
     */
    public getHTTP(): string {
        const protocol = (this.secure ? "https" : "http");

        return this.getEndpoint(protocol);
    }

    /**
     * getWS returns the WebSocket baseDomain string.
     * * If the baseDomain is secure it returns WSS.
     */
    public getWS(): string {
        const protocol = (this.secure ? "wss" : "ws");

        return this.getEndpoint(protocol);
    }

    private cloneEndpoint(): Endpoint {
        return new Endpoint(this.secure, this.baseDomain, this.paths, this.port);
    }

    private getEndpoint(protocol: string) {
        const port = (this.port ? ":" + this.port : "");

        let endpoint = protocol + "://" + this.baseDomain + port;

        endpoint += this.getPath();

        if (this.queries.size) {
            endpoint += "?";

            let first = true;
            for (const key of this.queries.keys()) {
                if (!first) {
                    endpoint += "&";
                }

                endpoint += key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(this.queries.get(key));

                first = false;
            }
        }

        return  endpoint;
    }

    private getPath(): string {
        let fullPath = "";

        for (const path of this.paths) {
            fullPath += "/" + path;
        }

        return fullPath;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like a TypeScript compiler bug.  I tried briefly to reproduce it based on the code you provided and wasn't successful.  Can you publish a repository that reproduces the bug?  Then maybe we can determine whether it's the same as [one of the existing bugs with similar error messages](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+%22Debug+Failure.+False+expression.%22).

Comment: I can give the class that gives the bug. See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the error with TypeScript 2.9.2.  Stack trace:

```
Error: Debug Failure. False expression.
    at Object.getJSDocTags (.../typescript/lib/tsc.js:10302:22)
    at getJSDocTypeParameterDeclarations (.../typescript/lib/tsc.js:9069:30)
    at Object.getEffectiveTypeParameterDeclarations (.../typescript/lib/tsc.js:9065:67)
    at checkClassLikeDeclaration (.../typescript/lib/tsc.js:40190:36)
    at checkClassExpression (.../typescript/lib/tsc.js:40166:13)
    at checkExpressionWorker (.../typescript/lib/tsc.js:37693:28)
    at checkExpression (.../typescript/lib/tsc.js:37629:42)
    at checkBinaryLikeExpression (.../typescript/lib/tsc.js:37246:29)
    at checkBinaryExpression (.../typescript/lib/tsc.js:37238:20)
    at checkExpressionWorker (.../typescript/lib/tsc.js:37717:28)
```

I don't see an existing issue, but I don't get the error with either TypeScript 3.0.3 or 3.1.3.  I suggest you try 3.0.3 again and try to confirm that that version is actually being used.  (An easy way would be to stick an `unknown` somewhere in your code and see if it is recognized.)

Another avenue for a solution would be to stop TypeScript from loading the problematic JavaScript file.  I'm not familiar with the Angular build system to know all of your options, but one thing that is likely to be possible is to turn on declaration file (`.d.ts`) generation for your library and ensure that the resulting `.d.ts` file is present alongside the `.js` file when you build the application, so TypeScript will load the `.d.ts` file instead of the `.js` file.  This will likely give you superior type information too.

Comment: `3.0.3` is not supported by Angular so this is not a stable solution and building for production results in an error. If I compile the library with `3.0.3` I also get the error.

Comment: I added another possible solution.  As I said, I can't reproduce the error on 3.0.3; if you'd like me to investigate the 3.0.3 situation further, you'll need to publish a repository that reproduces the problem for you (you can remove any confidential information).